# Htaccess or html: redirect to a rewritten URL

Tags: html, .htaccess, apache2

[Heavily edited]

I currently have access restricted using .htaccess files via: AuthName; AuthUserFile and AuthGroup directives.

I am hoping to have a 'user redirect' page protected by htaccess, which when prompted for login credentials initiates a redirect to the users area via the .htaccess file. Each user area contains different content in it's own directory so i would need to rewrite the username to the end of the url.

For example:

From:

> https:// www.domain.com/index.html

To:

> https:// www.domain.com/{user1}/index.html for user1

Or:

> https:// www.domain.com/{user2}/index.html for user2

So far this is the best i have jumbled together via extrapolation:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1!^user1/ 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} ^user1$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https:// www.domain.com/user1/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond $1!^user2/ 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} ^user2$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https:// www.domain.com/user2/$1 [L]
```

or possibly

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.+/
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Are either correct and/or is there a better way to do it? It would be good to not have to add lines for each user

NOTE/EDIT: Php is a bit complicated for me at present. Query about php now removed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very (I do mean *very*) basic (and truncated) general workflow of a login situation. If you don't know PHP (which it sounds like you don't) it's going to be near impossible to do this by yourself as a "I-think-I'll-take-a-crack-at-this" plan. You may want to try a ready-made solution like Wordpress.

**login.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="process.php">
            User: <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
            Pass: <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
session_start();
// Add whatever your database connection is...this is a PDO example...
include_once('database.config.php');
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {

    // absurdly-simplified validation...
    $username = (!empty($_POST['username']))? $_POST['username']:false;
    $password = (!empty($_POST['password']))? $_POST['password']:false;

    // If validate input is good
    if($username != false && $password != false) {
            // Encrypt password however it's stored in your db
            $password = whatever_encrypt_thing($password);

            // Do a call to your database
            $query = $con->prepare("select * from users where username = :username and password = :password");
            $query->execute(array(':username'=>$username,':password'=>$password));
            // etc...do code to validate user and assign $_SESSION stuff.
            // Lets pretend $valid is the final return...

            if($valid == true)
                // Redirect to success page where each user gets their links
                header('Location: success.php');
            // Stop script from further processing.
            exit;
        }
}

// Redirect to login
header('Location: login.php?error=login');
```

Comment: I agree, that is a bit impossible for me as a bit of a "I-think-I'll-take-a-crack-at-this" plan. While i get the basic idea of what the script is doing the syntax doesn't make sense at present since i have no context/backgound. At present i would have a real fight having to also make database.config.php and extrapolate from the above example. I think this will have to be contained to a 'in the pipeline' learning 'thing'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't typically want to use the form's `action = ""` method for re-directing the user. The action method is used to decide where the form's values (stored in the $_POST or $_GET arrays depending on your form's method) is sent for validation, processing or whatever else you want to do with it. The validation, processing, or whatever-else-you-want-to-do-with-it page would then hold the redirection requests (typically using the `header()` function) if your code requires it. @Rasclatt posted a very good example of such code.

Just to give you another example, this is a pseudo-code version of how the code may look.  @Rasclatt's answer is more detailed in terms of what you would do with your database. Functions similar to his would be used for the `userHasRegisteredEmail()` and `userHasMatchingPasswords()` functions below. The following is a form that allows users to login by sending the script back to the page that contains the form.

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

//Connect to database
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception only for development mode
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

//Checks the $_POST array to see if it contains 'submit'. If so, you know the form was submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Declare variables and reset Form Values
    $email = $password = null;

    //Store form values. Trim() is used to erase excess whitespace in form values.
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    //You can add some validation here if you'd like.

    //Process Form Values
    if (userHasRegisteredEmail() && userHasMatchingPassword()) {
          logUserIn();
          header('location: user-profile.php'); //REDIRECT USER TO PROFILE PAGE
          exit(); //Ensures that the rest of the script isn't run after redirection
    } else {
          showUserLogInError();
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        //Leaving form's action empty, i.e. action="", will send the form values back to the current page
        <form method="POST" action="">
            User: <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
            Pass: <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps. Also, things like this are a breeze with php and [PHPAcademy's youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpOIUW62tnJTtpWFABxWZ8g) have some awesome tutorials. I hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Seems you edited the question as I was posting an answer. Sorry, if it's no longer helpful.

Comment: It is most definitely helpful. My initial question has been modified so i can implement a solution until i can put the time in to learn to use php. I do intend to get my head around php and mysql in the future and this will be useful reference! Thank you for taking the time, it is not wasted. :)